# let $A^r=I$ and $a$ be the only eigen-calue ,then prove that $A=aI$.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, linear-transformations

We assume for the sake of contradiction that $A \ne aI$.

Since $A^r=I$ ,where $A$ is a $n \times n$ matrix, then we can conclude that $A$ has rank n since the nullspace(A) is a subset of nullspace of $A^r$.Also since $a$ is the only eigen value of $A$ then $a^r =1$,so $a$ can be anyone of the following  $ cos(\frac{2k\pi}{r})+isin(\frac{2k\pi}{r})$ where $k=0,1,2,..,r-1$.Since I have considered the field of scalars to be $\mathbb{C}$ so , the characteristic polynomial will split in the field $\mathbb{C}$ into linear factor .

Also,the minimal polynomial  of $A$ will be $(x-a)^{r_1}(x-a_1)^{r_2}(x-a_2)^{r_3}....(x-a_{n-1})^{r_n}$, where ${r_1}+...+{r_n} \le n$.Now,I am trying to conclude it in this way as the minimal polynomial of $A$ divides the minimal polynomial of $A^r$ ( which is my guess from the definition of the minimal polynomial- let $m(x)= x^n +a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+....+a_0$.Now ,$m(A)=0$ and $A^n+a_{n-1}A^{n-1}+...+a_oI=0$ also, if we multiply the whole equation by $A^r$ we get $(A^r)^n+....+a_0A^r=0$).Hence,$((x-a)^{r_1}...(x-a_{n})^{r_n})|(x-1)(x-(cos(\frac{2k\pi}{r}))..(x-cos(\frac{2(r-1)\pi}{r})$,hence $r_1=1,r_2=1,...,r_n=1$.So the minimal polynomial is a linear factor so $A$ can be written in the form of a diagonal matrix , but we know that $a$ is the only eigen-value ,so $A=aI$.

I don't think my solution is correct.Some hints(not the full answer) would be helpful.

Comment: I think it's a bit confused but basically it has the right ideas. (i) If $A^r-I=0$ then $m_A\mid x^r-1$. (ii) $x^r-1$ is a product of distinct linear factors as you rightly say. (iii) Hence $m_A$ is a product of distinct linear factors [You say "is a linear factor" which is not yet true. ](iv) The roots of $m_A$ are all eigenvalues, and you are given that there is only one eigenvalue $a$; hence $m_a=x-a$. (v) Hence $A-aI=0$.